# Using with() and find() while limiting columns with find cancels relation data

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following code that displays different data depending on if you are the authenticated user looking at your own data or if you are looking at data from another user. The code works but in my opinion is very nasty.

```
public function showUserDetailed(Request $request, $username)
    {
    $key = strtolower($username).'-data-detailed';

    if(Auth::user()->usenrame === $username) {
        $key = $key .'-own';
    }

    if(Cache::has($key)) {
        if($request->wantsJson()) {
            return request()->json(Cache::get($key));
        } else {
            return view('user/detailed', ['user' => Cache::get($key)]);
        }
    } else {
        if(Auth::user()->username === $username) {
            $u = User::where('username', $username)->first();

            $user = new \stdClass();
            $user->username = $u->username;
            $user->email = $u->email;
            $user->address = $u->address;
            $user->city = $u->city;
            $user->state = $u->state;
            $user->zip = $u->zip;
            $user->phone = $u->phone;
            $user->follows = $u->follows;
            $user->ratings = $u->ratings;
            $user->location = $u->location;
        } else {
            $u = User::where('username', $username)->first(['username', 'city', 'state']);

            $user = new \stdClass();
            $user->username = $u->username;
            $user->city = $u->city;
            $user->state = $u->state;
            $user->follows = $u->follows;
            $user->ratings = $u->ratings;
        }

        Cache::put($key, $user);

        if($request->wantsJson()) {
            return response()->json($user);
        } else {
            return view('user/detailed', ['user' => $user]);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to use something similar to the following in the model calls.

```
User::where('username', $username)->with('follows', 'ratings', 'location')->find(['username', 'city', 'state');
```

However when I specify the columns to get from the user table it negates the relation data so it comes back as empty arrays. Is there a different way I can do this which would be cleaner? I despise having to create a stdClass to be a data container in this situation and feel I may be missing something.

```
// this works
User::where('username', $username)->with('follows', 'ratings', 'location')->first();

// this also works
User::where('username', $username)->first(['username', 'city', 'state']);

// this does not
User::where('username', $username)->with('follows', 'ratings', 'location')->first(['username', 'city', 'state']);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you specify columns and want to get the related models as well, you need to include `id` (or whatever foreign key you're using) in the selected columns.

The relationships execute another query like this:

```
SELECT 'stuff' FROM 'table' WHERE 'foreign_key' = ($parentsId)
```

So it needs to know the id of the parent (original model). Same logic applies to all relationships in a bit different forms.

Comment: In this case I cannot do that because the id is not stored in the user table.  A user can have many follows and the user_id is stored in the related 'follows' table.  Therefore when using User:: I cannot provide a follow id to load the relation, is there not a way to just load all relations like this?  I should also note these are Polymorphic relations. (follow, ratings, location)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to say here "Therefore when using User:: I cannot provide a follow id to load the relation". And what do you mean that id is not stored in the user table? How is the "follows" model connected to it then?

Comment: The UserId is stored in the follows table as followable_id along side followable_type.  As stated this is a polymorphic relation.  As you can see in the docs posts and videos do not contain a comments id..

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Comment: @JosephCrawford Can you try this and get back to me if it doesn't work? `User::select('users.id', 'users.username', 'users.state', 'users.city')->where('username', $username)->with('follows', 'ratings', 'location')->first()`

Comment: This does not seem to work either, this is what is returned, notice follows and ratings are empty since they are not included in the with().


    {
      "id": 201,
      "username": "joseph",
      "state": null,
      "city": null,
      "follows": [],
      "ratings": [],
      "location": {
        "id": 3297,
        "locatable_id": 201,
        "locatable_type": "User",
        "latitude": 42.9304,
        "longitude": 73.2426,
        "updated_at": "2017-01-04 13:32:58"
      }
    }